# how do i perform a url redirection and masking?

Tags: php, url-masking

I have url where i host my webinars which is provided by webinar hosting provider. I would like to change that url to something within my domain.

For eg. The webinar url is something like
http://www.onlinemeetingnow.com/seminar/?id=d181a7640e

i would like to change it look something within my domain.

www.mywebsite.com/webinar

Is this possible?

Comment: halo, at least show us you are using apache, IIS, nginx ?????

Comment: Is there only one webpage or a complete website with links and all ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want to create that page(s) on your own site and within that page you load the onlinemeetingnow url. This can be done with an iframe or such or you can get the html code from the page (with Curl or something) and than load that into your own page.

Comment: it worked by using the framesets, i just gave frame src to onlinemeeting url. @Baszz idea of iframes just lit the bulb in my head

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way of doing this would be to create a PHP script at the desired URL that simply does a readfile () of the target URL.  That would give the appearance that your site is hosting the remotely hosted content.

```
<?php

readfile ('http://www.onlinemeetingnow.com/seminar/?id=d181a7640e');

?>
```

This approach does require allow_url_fopen to be enabled, which it might not be for security reasons.  It also has issues regarding such things as cookies, for example.  Say you are using this trick to link to a remote site that requires a login and uses cookies to implement it, people who are logged into the remote site would appear not to be logged in, as their cookie wouldn't be sent to the remote site when you readfile () it.

You could use curl instead, as you have a bit more control, and it doesn't require allow_url_fopen.  It still wouldn't be ideal though.

If you can configure your server, you could possibly use something like proxypass or URL rewriting to hide the remote URL.

Other solutions include using an iframe to display the remote site, or using AJAX to load the remote page's markup and inject into your page, but these approaches have their own set of issues that you need to take into account.

In the end, is it really worth the effort needed and the compromises you will have to make to just have the URL appear to be locally hosted when it isn't?

Comment: Relative (internal) links in the webpage wont work with that solution, if there are any.

Comment: The OP made no mention of internal links. Besides, I did say there were problems with all the above approaches.

Comment: He made no mention of it, but **if there are any**, then it won't work. I just wanted to make that clear for the OP, I didn't downvoted your answer.

Comment: Quite aside from relative links not working with this method, not even the images appear! I can not imagine a web page in this day and age without, at very least, a link and / or image, so this suggested solution does not work at the best of times.

Comment: This is a nice solution. I did this inside a php mvc framework, and readfile() immediately re-reads the index.php it was called from. You can pass a GET variable to provisionally bypass that.